# Mixed Joint Probability

Tags: probability, density-function, joint-distribution

In the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case) they give the example of a logistic regression problem to predict $P(Y=y\,|\,X=x)$ where $Y$ is binary (discrete) and $X$ is a continuous random variable. Then the mixed joint density is:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(Y=y\,|\,X=x)f_X(x)$$
How come it is ok to refer to the probability of $X=x$ when $X$ has a continuous density function, i.e., when $P(X=x)=0$? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Y=y | X = x)$ is a conditional distribution. It does not refer to $P(X = x)$, but to the probability that $Y = y$ given that $X = x$.

You can think of it like this: imagine that you have a device that won't turn on if you feed a voltage below 10V, but will work with 50% chance if its above or equal.

Consider that the voltage is a random variable with continuous distribution, so $P(V=v) = 0$ for any value of $v$. But once you measured it, you got 10.12V. What is $P($turn on$ | V = 10.12)$? I mean, what is the probability that the device will turn on given that you measured V = 10.12V?

Comment: Thanks for the nice example.